# Do I need permissions to access a Facbooker's Facebook user ID?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Do I need permissions to access a Facbooker's Facebook user ID in the following case:

1. The user is logged into Facebook.
2. The user then follows a link from Facebook to my webpage.
3. My webpage grabs their Facebook user ID (Is this part possible without asking for special permissions from the user?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to identify that the user is indeed logged into Facebook, you need to follow one of the authentication paths to find out if they are indeed a user. Facebook won't give you any information about a random web visitor unless they have logged in and authenticated your site.